# Backbone listen to change of collection after ajax

Tags: backbone.js

Trying to figure out how to add a listener to my application that will listen for a change or addition to the model or collection - and then re-render the view.

If you look at the console during load of this page, it does a ajax request and add's 659 objects to the collection. Although it does not render the items after it does this request.

https://foodtrucks-c9-gregegan.c9.io/foodtrucks-backbone/

My assumption was to add the following line of code to the AllFoodTrucksView.js initialize() function. But that did not seem to work.
`this.collection.on("reset add change", this.render);`

THanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is solve the problem of the view not rendering the 659 items after completion of AJAX request, you could do something like:

```
foodTruckGroup.fetch().done(function() { foodTruckGroupView.render(); });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I found it was best to bind on reset of collection to re-render the view.
this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch({reset:true}).complete(function() {});